# Polynomial cube equation

Tags: polynomials

2 cubes have all sides and bases painted.
One cube's side length is 4 cm longer than the other cube's side length. 
If the larger cube needed 56 square cm more paint than the smaller cube, what is the side length of the smaller cube?

```
 if the side length  of the smaller cube is x, 
   then the side length of the bigger cube is x+4

   surface area of the smaller cube is 6x^2 square cm, 
   surface area of the larger cube is  6(x+4)^2 = 6x^2 + 48x + 96 square cm

  the equation is 
   6x^2 + 48x + 96 = 6x^2 + 56
   48x +96 = 56
   48x = -40
    x = -5/6
```

I am confused, how can a side length be negative?

Comment: I read the problem to have each cube have $5$ faces painted-the base and the four sides but not the top.  This does not solve the problem.  It changes $x$ to $-\frac 35$ but it is still negative.  The math part of your solution is correct, our disagreement is reading the English.  I would ask for an explanation from the problem setter.  +1 for showing your work and identifying the issue.

Comment: Did the source of the problem have a proposed solution? Maybe one could reverse engineer that to see what solver did... as you note something is off.

Comment: This is what they call "the problem has no solution".